# cpprestsdk (casablanca) json value to std::vector<unsigned char>

Tags: c++, json, vector, byte, casablanca

I am using [cpprestsdk](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk)  in order to create http client. I need to convert `web::json::value` like this:

```
web::json::value obj;
obj[U("1")] = web::json::value(U("123"));
obj[U("2")] = web::json::value(U("321"));
```

to `std::vector<unsigned char>`

In order to put it to request

```
web::http::http_request req(method);
req.set_body(data); <<-- data == std::vector<unsigned char>
```

and send to the server. I know how to send `web::json::value` and `utility::string_t` but have the problem with vector of bytes. **So my question is how to convert** `web::json::value` **to** `std::vector<unsigned char>`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, are you sure you need to convert? The docs say there's a set_body overload for json::value.

If yes, then you can convert to a utf-8 string (that's what the code in set_body does), then copy to a vector.

```
auto text = utility::conversions::to_utf8string(obj.serialize());

std::vector<unsigned char> data(text.size());
std::transform(text.begin(), text.end(), data.begin(),
    [](char ch)
{
    return static_cast<unsigned char>(ch);
});
```

Comment: Sounds like solution.